# Loop an array of string in a p tag

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a array of strings and I want to loop in a `<p>` tag if the array is null.

I have something like this in this moment:

```
  <p *ngIf="detailMessageMultilines">{{detailMessageMultilines}}</p>
```

I want to loop the array `detailMessageMultilines` and I was thinking to use `ng-repeat` but I don't know how.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Look into `*ngFor`: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ngFor and ngIf in the same line, so make sure you're intitializing your array first

```
detailMessageMultilines:any = []
```

Then use *ngFor for the repeat

```
  <p *ngFor="let p of detailMessageMultilines">{{p}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of users">{{item.text}}</li>
</ul>
```

```
 users = [
    {text: 'a'},
    {text: 'b'},
    {text: 'c'},
  ];
```